# My content is not adjusting inside div

Tags: html, css

[My Screenshot of page](http://feb.imghost.us/EycU.png)

I'm new to designing layout.

I've made this layout but it's not expanding the inner div within container whenever i add more text or any element inside it. kindly correct my css.

Here's the css of my layout

> ```
> @charset "utf-8";
> /* CSS Document */
> @media only screen
> {
> #fullPage
> {
>     width:1100px;
>     height:850px;
>     position:relative;
>     margin:auto;
>     background-color:#999999;
> }
>     header
> {
>     width:100%;
>     height:200px;
>     position:relative;
>     background-color:red;
> }
> header > nav
> {
>     width:50%;
>     height:50%;
>     margin:auto;
>     position:relative;
>     background-color:lime;
> }
> #mobile
> {
>     display:none;   
>     background-color:orange;
> }
> #fullPage > section
> {
>     width:100%;
>     height:100%;
>     min-height:500px;
>     position:relative;
>     background-color:yellow;
> }    section > aside, section > section
> {
>     width:500px;
>     height:100%;
>     position:absolute;
>     top:0px;
>     left:0px;
>     background-color:pink;
> }
> section > aside~aside
> {
>     width:100px;
>     left:1000px;
> }
> section > section
> {
>     left:500px;
>     background-color:blue;
> }
> footer
> {
>     width:100%;
>     height:150px;
>     position:relative;
>     background-color:red;
> }
> }
> @media only screen and (max-width:1024px) and (min-width:801px)
> {
> #fullPage
> {
>     width:1000px;
> }
> header > nav
> {
>     background-color:pink;
> }
> section > aside~aside
> {
>     display:none;
> }   
> }
> @media only print
> {
> }
> @media only screen and (max-width:800px)
> {
> #fullPage
> {
>     width:640px;
>     height:1350px;
> }
> header
> {
>     background-color:lime;
> }
> header > nav
> {
>     width:75%;
>     height:50%;
>     margin:auto;
> }
> #mobile
> {
>     display:block;  
> }
> #desktop
> {
>     display:none;   
> }
> #fullPage > section
> {
>     height:1000px;
> }
> section > aside, section > section
> {
>     width:100%;
>     height:50%;
>     position:relative;
>     left:0px;
> }
> section > aside~aside
> {
>     display:none;
> }
> }
> ```

This is My HTML

```
<div id="fullPage">
 <header> 
  <nav id="desktop">DESKTOP</nav> 
  <nav id="mobile">MOBILE</nav> 
</header>
<section> 
 <aside>menu-1</aside>
 <section>Lorem Ipsum is Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority</section>
 <aside>menu-2</aside>
</section>
 <footer>footer-1</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS without any html to apply it to is rather pointless/useless.

Comment: http://feb.imghost.us/EycU.png

Comment: a picture of rendered html is useless as well... show the ACTUAL html... just the html. we don't need text contents.

Comment: My divs are not expanding their heights with content inside them neither container

Comment: How to show my html here?

Comment: same way you put in your css...

Comment: I've edited my post. now check it Marc B

Comment: Well what do you expect when setting `#fullPage` to a fixed `height:850px` …? If you want a _minimal_ height, then use `min-height` …

Comment: as @CBroe suggested you should not use a fixed height if you want your container div to increase its height as soon as a new content is added. change the height value of your container div to auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner "section" element has position:absolute; hence it doesn't "stretch" it's containing element's height (set to 500px).
What you actually want to do is not use position:absolute; so your elements' heights can be more dynamically, using "float" methodology.

I would recommend following this:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/ss/css_layout_sbs.htm

Comment: Thanks ronen. It worked but how to do this same effect without using float?

Comment: If it actually works for you, an Up vote would be highly appreciated :-) 
Can i ask why do you want to avoid using 'float'? It seems like that is exactly what you should do...

Comment: In your case, the usage of "position:absolute;" is not good, because you want the height of the container to be dynamically according to it's actual content. You can see that if you remove the "height:500px;", it will actually get height of 0px... only if you remove the "position:absolute;", you container stretches.
"position:absolute;" is used to position elements in a fixed position/dimentions, regardless of their content- which in your case, is NOT want you are trying to achieve.